# FileSystemWatcher to execute .NET functions

Tags: .net, powershell, filesystemwatcher

I am creating a quick temporary fix so sorry if this is dirty, but-

**Objective**

I would like to use Powershells Register-Event cmd to wait for a file dropped in a folder, then call a function that parses the file and outputs it to excel. I don't need help with the coding aspect, just the concept. It is still a little mysterious to me as of where this Event is running and what resources it has to work with.

**Things I've Tried**

1. One .ps1 file with registered events at the bottom, calling a function at the top, called by a batch file.
   *Behavior:* Stops on this line:

   ```
   $sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($copyPath)
   ```

   This is my first invocation of .NET, so this is why I was assuming it is an issue with .NET.
2. Two .ps1 files, FileWatcher and Parser, both work great when run separately, called by a batch file.
   *Behavior:* FileWatcher Outputs "This Line" but fails to output any lines in Parser, and never gets to that line.

   ```
   Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChange -Action {
     Write-Host "This Line"
     .\src\Parser.ps1
     Write-host "That Line"
   }
   ```
3. I even got as desperate as to go to two ps1 files and two batch files. Lets just say it didn't work.

Generic batch file command I am using:

```
powershell.exe -noexit C:\scripts\src\FileWatcher.ps1
```

**Questions**

Why does certain commands run fine when called from a registered event, and other commands like .NET not work?

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible?

Do you have a better way to achieve my objective? (Scripting only, remember this is a hotfix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me (code mostly copied from [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)):

```
$folder = 'c:\Temp'
$filter = '*.*'

$monitor = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
  IncludeSubdirectories = $false;
  NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

Register-ObjectEvent $monitor Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
  $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
  $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($name)
  Write-Host $sr.ReadToEnd()
  $sr.Close()
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, you showed me that it is not a .net problem at all. I figured out my line was getting to an error and stopping. Also, now that I got it finally all to run, it outputs verbose statements but seems like its keeping all write-host statements in a stack and outputting them all at the end. I would like the code to handle errors smoothly and keep running like it normally would if I ran it outside a Event. I tried setting $ErrorActionPreference = Continue . Also, I'm still looking for a simple explanation on how these processes work. I just crashed my work pc due to hundreds of PS process

Comment: Closing out question because original problem was resolved. Could only make this work by adding error checking everywhere. Please reply if you have a better solution.